# Herkunft von "in die Röhre gucken"?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Wenn jemand "in die Röhre guckt", dann ist er/sie benachteiligt worden oder hat etwas nicht geschafft. Aber woher kommt diese Redewendung?

Comment: Hmm, modern könnte ich mir auch fast vorstellen, dass Leute, die immer nur in die Röhre gucken (also fernsehen, Röhre hin oder her), letztendlich etwas benachteiligt sind...

Comment: Ja, ich hatte auch das Fernsehen im Verdacht. Allerdings eher in der Interpretation, dass man direkt in die Röhre reinschaut, wenn kein Bild da ist (z.B. weil der Fernseher kaputt ist).

Comment: Ich hätte das mit der Ofenröhre in Zusammenhang gebracht, die dann leer ist, wenn's einem nicht so gut geht. Daher wäre "in die Röhre gucken" eine Beschreibung dass man leer ausgegangen ist und nichts essbares in die Ofenröhre schieben kann.

Comment: Könnte es sein, dass die Backröhre gemeint ist, und zwar die leere Backröhre? Man hofft dort einen Braten zu finden, macht auf... und nix is. So eine Redewendung ist ja meist relativ alt und stammt also aus der Zeit bevor es die Fernsehröhre gab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hierzu habe ich Folgendes gefunden:

Quelle [Cosmiq.de](http://www.cosmiq.de/qa/show/2885660/in-ein-das-Ofenrohr-schauen-quelle-http-www-gruene-at-skandale-artikel-lesen-67340/)
In der deutschen Armee wurde das Raketenrohr 'Ofenrohr' genannt. Vor dem Laden muss sich der Lader durch einen Blick ins Rohr vergewissern, dass nichts drin ist – ins Ofenrohr schauen bzw. in die Röhre schauen – und rufen: "Rohr frei!"

Daher auch "leer ausgehen"

Comment: Kommen daher auch andauernd diese Schüsse in den Ofen?

Comment: Die Quelle scheint mir nicht besonders zuverlässig zu sein. Übrigens stimmt m.E. "Daher auch..." nicht.

Comment: Die Quelle ist inzwischen verwaist.

Answer (score 7):

Duden – Redewendungen, 3. Aufl. Mannheim 2008:

> **in die Röhre gucken** (ugs.): 1. *leer ausgehen; das Nachsehen haben:* (…)
>
> - In der ersten Bedeutung ist die Herkunft dieser Wendung nicht sicher geklärt. Vielleicht stammt sie aus der Jägersprache, wo »Röhre« den Bau (des Dachses) bezeichnet. In die Röhre kann der Hund hineinsehen, aber nicht hineinkriechen.

Comment: Ich finde Dudens vorsichtige Hypothese nicht Übel, aber auch die Hypothese mit dem Kanonenrohr ist nicht schlecht. Aber letzten Endes weiß man nichts Genaues.

Answer (score 4):

1865, Breslauer Zeitung: "in die Röhre kieken" - soweit ich weiß, wurde das Fernsehen erst später erfunden...

Comment: Kann man das näher eingrenzen, als "1865"? Wie oft erschien denn die Zeitung? Prächtig wäre noch ein Link. Außerdem beantwortet es nicht die Frage, sondern widerlegt nur eine Antwort (hoppla, das ist ja meine), weshalb es zu dieser als Kommentar gepostet werden sollte. Mit belastbarem Link werde ich meine Antwort dann zurückziehen.

Answer (score 3):

Also ich gehe davon aus, dass *in die Röhre schauen* nichts mit dem TV zu tun hat. Der Begriff wurde wohl schon 1865 verwendet. Zudem spricht man im Ruhrpott von *bei Mannesmann in die Röhre schauen*. Und wofür stehen Mannesmannröhren? Für nahtlose Röhren! Diese waren wohl in der Wehrtechnik eine Innovation. Für mich macht also die Prüfung eines Ladeschützen beim Nachladen Sinn.

Comment: Welchen Beleg für 1865 hast Du denn? Google-Books findet vor 1955 nichts. Null.

Answer (score 3):

Ich habe in [»Verbale Phraseolexeme in System und Text« von Barbara Wotjak, S.31](https://books.google.gr/books?id=7O-oqAQUjjQC&pg=PA19&dq=%22in%20die%20r%C3%B6hre%22&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q=%22in%20die%20r%C3%B6hre%22&f=false) noch Erklärungsansätze eines gewissen Röhrich gefunden (vermutlich aus »Lexikon der sprichwörtlichen Redensarten“, L. Röhrich 1973) . Dieser schon allein des Nachnames wegen qualifizierte Autor mutmaßte:

> Das Bild ist entweder vom Fernrohr genommen, mit dem man ‚[in den Mond guckt](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~in%20den%20Mond%20gucken&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)‘ (was ja die selbe Bedeutung hat), oder von der [Abtrittsröhre](https://www.google.at/search?q=abtrittsr%C3%B6hre&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari), wodurch Verwandtschaft mit dem gleichbedeutenden ‚[in den Eimer sehen](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~jemand%20guckt%20in%20den%20Eimer&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_varianten_ou)‘ besteht.

Answer (score 2):

Röhre könnte eine Verkürzung von Fernsehröhre sein. In die Röhre schauen wäre also fernsehen, und bedeuten könnte es, dass man, während andere etwas unternehmen/tun man untätig dasitzt und fernsieht.
[image]

Dafür spricht, dass der Ausdruck erst nach den 60ern populär wird.

[https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+die+R%C3%B6hre+gucken&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20die%20R%C3%B6hre%20gucken%3B%2Cc0](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20die%20R%C3%B6hre%20gucken&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20die%20R%C3%B6hre%20gucken%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Vielleicht ist auch "gucken" das Problem bei dieser suche.
"In die Röhre" ist nämlich auch vorher häufig.

Comment: Es kann sich auch um eine Volksetymologie handeln, sodass die Verwendung mit dem Auftauchen des Röhrenfernsehens zwar ansteigt, die ursprüngliche Bedeutung aber eine andere war.

Comment: Von 1600 bis 1955: 0 Fundstellen. Null, nada, zero, keine.

Comment: @TGlatzer: Ja, man kann nach "schauen, sehen, kieken, luken, starren" suchen sowie nach anderen Wortstellungen "gucken in die Röhre", anderem Numerus "in die Röhre guckt", andere Zeitform "in die Röhre guckte" usw. NGram bietet leider kein Interface, um das zu unterstützen.