# Herkunft von "Mit dem Ofenrohr ins Gebirge schauen"

Tags: etymology, phrase

Der Ausdruck scheint aus dem Bayrischen zu kommen und bedeutet, dass alle Anstrengungen vergebens waren und man leer ausgeht. Aber wie kam es zu dieser Redewendung?

Es dürfte eine Verwandtschaft zu [In die Röhre gucken](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1531/herkunft-von-in-die-r%c3%b6hre-gucken/1535#1535) bestehen.

Answer (score 3):

Mit dem Alphorn hat das bestimmt nichts zu tun.

Ich bin Bayer und spreche schon immer bayrisch. Diesen Spruch kenne ich von Kindheitsbeinen an, von einem Bezug zum Alphorn habe ich noch nie gehört.

Ich denke das Ofenrohr (die Röhre) wird hier bildlich von einfachen Gemütern als (ähnlich aussehendes) Teleskop benutzt, was natürlich scheitert.

Für die etwas Jüngeren: ein Ofenrohr ist keine Backröhre, sondern ein Metallrohr, das die Abgase von einem Holzofen oder -herd zum Kamin führt und dabei das Zimmer heizt.

Comment: Mir kommt das als Analogie zu einem Faschingsumzugswagen vor: Ein tatsächliches Ofenrohr, montiert auf einem Stativ, und einer der Narren beobachtet dadurch die Zuschauer / die Szene / das Gebirge / den Mond. In Ermangelung einer Linse ist die Wirkung natürlich Null.

Answer (score 1):

Normal schaut man mit einem Fernrohr ins Gebirge. Hat man es sich allerdings mit einer Person verdorben und bekommt als Reaktion dafür nichts mehr (zu sehen), schaut man nicht mehr mit einem hochwertigen optischen Gerät ins schöne Gebirge, sondern muss statt dessen mit einem primitiven Ofenrohr vorlieb nehmen und bekommt nichts mehr zu sehen. Man geht also leer aus im übertragenen Sinne.

Answer (score 0):

Am wahrscheinlichsten halte ich, dass es auf eine humorvolle Übertragung von "in den/die Mond/Röhre gucken" <sup>([1](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=%7E%7Ein%20den%20Mond%20gucken&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou))</sup> auf (zur Entstehungszeit) typische Alltagsdinge im Alpenland zurückzuführen ist. Vielleicht steht das Ofenrohr sogar für eine Verballhornung des Alphorns (Spekulation!). Zumindest wird bildlich sehr gut klargestellt, dass Sinnloses ohne Ergebnis bleibt.

Comment: Das finde ich nicht überzeugend, aber dafür originell (+1). Vielleicht hat der Ausdruck mehrere Bedeutungen, mein Verständnis ist, dass alle Anstrengungen (die nicht sinnlos zu sein brauchen) ohne Ergebnis blieben.